# How to sort an associative object array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

We have a Mario Kart tournament at work and I wanted to try and log the results using basic JavaScript.

Here's the code: https://jsbin.com/hafati/44/edit?js,console

I've nearly got there, but I need help sorting the results.

Here's the `console.log` of the data:

```
[object Object] {
  1: [object Object] {
    id: 1,
    name: "Player 1",
    total: 20
  },
  2: [object Object] {
    id: 2,
    name: "Player 2",
    total: 60
  },
  3: [object Object] {
    id: 3,
    name: "Player 3",
    total: 80
  },
  4: [object Object] {
    id: 4,
    name: "Player 4",
    total: 400
  },
  5: [object Object] {
    id: 5,
    name: "Player 5",
    total: 150
  },
  6: [object Object] {
    id: 6,
    name: "Player 6",
    total: 50
  }
}
```

How would you sort these players, with the highest `total` first?

Comment: I would put them in an array not an object, then sort them

Comment: indeed, make results an array instead of Object, then the sort will work

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks guys! @Mike The title of that post was misleading, but seems to be a similar problem. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to store data in array of objects, this will be **easier to iterate** over array than objects and will also **ensure the order** of elements. Then you can use array `sort` function to sort the array elements.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6u8y5xwt/)

```js
var myArr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Player 1",
  total: 20
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "Player 2",
  total: 60
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: "Player 3",
  total: 80
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: "Player 4",
  total: 400
}, {
  id: 5,
  name: "Player 5",
  total: 150
}, {
  id: 6,
  name: "Player 6",
  total: 50
}];


myArr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.total < b.total;
});
console.log(myArr);
```

Comment: @daveaspinall if this answer solved your issue please consider accepting an answer.

Comment: I have to wait five minutes before I can accept, already tried :-) Will of course accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript array functions are polymorphic, so you can use them on "array like" objects just fine:

```
var obj = { 0 :  {total: 3}, 1 : {total: 1}, 2 : {total: 5}}; // your object
obj.length = 2; // need to set this manually.

var sorted = [].sort.call(obj, function(x,y){ return x.total - y.total; });
```

That said, it is always best to store sequential data in a sequential data structure like an array - so while this works it's not the best idea. I'm assuming you don't have a choice :)

Comment: You can also keep them sorted [in a sorted set](https://github.com/adamhooper/js-sorted-set).

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a array:

```
var score = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Player 1",
    total: 20
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: "Player 2",
    total: 60
  },
  ...
}];
```

Then use `Array.sort()`:

```
score.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a.total < b.total;
});
```